# Can't access Collections.Item property in sqlserver.dts.runtime with C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I recently implemented a solution to take an SSIS package and reconfigure the connection strings of the package using VB.net. The code is quite simple:

```
    Const packageLocation As String = "C:\mylocation"
    Dim app As New Application
    Dim pkg = app.LoadPackage(packageLocation, Nothing)

    pkg.Connections.Item(0).ConnectionString = "Data Source=MySource"
```

I need to write the same piece of code in C# because that is the native language of our QA team, however I can't seem to be able to access the Item property:

```
     const string PackageLocation = @"C:\MyLocation";
     Application app = new Application();
     Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(PackageLocation, null);

     pkg.Connections.Item(0).ConnectionString = "Data Source=Mysource";
```

I am not understanding why I cannot access Connections.Item in the C# version of my code, yet I can with the VB version. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What the QA team is going to do with Language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the array syntax uses square brackets:

```
pkg.Connections.Item[0].ConnectionString = "Data Source=Mysource";
```

Or, since `Item` appears to be the default indexer for the `Connections` class, just leave it out entirely:

```
pkg.Connections[0].ConnectionString = "Data Source=Mysource";
```

Comment: It looks like I made a mistake by copying over the VB code and using those darn paranths instead of the brackets. I simply removed .Item entirely and used the index by itself. Thanks Steve!